# Failed to obtain broadcast value

Tags: apache-spark

I create a spark application like below.

When run with local client mode, everything goes fine.
But when I submit into YARN with cluster deploy mode on prod environment, variable `applicationAction` in last match block always be `null`.

So is there any problem which I'm using broadcast here, or there's any other method I could pass the variables to the last match case block.

Thanks.

```scala
object SparkTask {
  private sealed trait AppAction {}
  case class Action1() extends AppAction
  case class Action2() extends AppAction

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var applicationAction: Broadcast[AppAction] = null
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkTask").getOrCreate

    args(0) match {
      case "action-1" => applicationAction = sparkSession.sparkContext.broadcast(Action1())
      case "action-2" => applicationAction = sparkSession.sparkContext.broadcast(Action2())
      case _ => sys.exit(255)
    }

    // Here goes some df action and get a persisted dataset
    val df1 = ...
    val df2 = ...
    val df3 = ...

    applicationAction.value match {
      case Action1() => handleAction1(df3)
      case Action2() => handleAction2(df3)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of broadcast variables it to share some data with executors.
I think in your use-case there are two possibilites:

- You're trying to get some information from executors to driver: for this you shouldn't use broadcast variables but accumulators or something like take/collect.
- You want take a decision based on applicationAction.value (immutable): in this case you can then use directly the value of *args(0)*.

Comment: Very appreciate your answer. The reason I use broadcast is I got null if I use applicationAction without broadcast it. So is it possible to use the variable which assigned from args(0) directly in `main` function  theoretically ?

Comment: @Francis.TM then you can use directly args(0) for doing something in the driver (the main function, but not some operation on DF or RDD)

Comment: I have found my bug, It has no issue about Spark or broadcast. Thanks.